# java: DynaBean.contains(String name, String key) - how to use it properly?

Tags: java, jdbc

I use List to fetch a ResultSet from an SQL query (using mysql).
After I fetch one row using

```
DynaBean row = rowList.get(0);
```

I would like to know if one of the columns named 'id' exists.

The problem is that the `row.contains()` function requires two parameters. `String name` and `String key`. I can't quite figure out how to use this function.

any ideas?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welp.. it's not the answer I wanted, but for now I can use the `get()` function to retrieve the rows and check using a try catch block and catching IllegalArgumentException which means that the column name is not available.

```
    List<DynaBean> rowsList=this._mysqlDb.foobar();
    Date timeStamp=null;
    for (int i=0;i<rowsList.size();i++) {
        DynaBean row = rowsList.get(i);
        try {
         timeStamp = this._mysqlDb.sqlTimestampToDate((java.sql.Timestamp)row.get("end_timestamp"));
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            log.error("could not find properties: {}",e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
}
```